# Vertical line under an image but over a background

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

As mentioned in the title, I want to make a vertical line in the center, under an image but over a background (just like in this example: http://www.akita.co.uk/computing-history/#decade2000). How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: If you'd take the time to inspect the code, you can see they make the line with an `::after` CSS psuedo-element.

Comment: Thank you skyline3000. Yes, I had inspected the code, but I'm a begginer and I didn't know how to use it. I also tried to write it but I couldn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achief this with a pseudo-element. I'll make a quick pen to show you how but basically, you just give the image a z-index of 2, the pseudo-element parent a z-index of 1 and you're good to go.

Keep in mind that the Z-index is inherited from the parent. So by using the -1 on the pseudo-element you are saying, take the parent z-index(2), and substract 1 from that, so you end up with a z-index of 1.

```
.image{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top:100px;
  &::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:300px;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background:red;
    z-index:-1;
  }
}
```

Example in the pen: http://codepen.io/jan-dh/pen/VjOEyq?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do this by using CSS to set the Z-index of your image? Setting a high z-index will bring it to the front of all of the other elements on your page.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp